# how to solve this Differential Equation : $(1+x^2)y''=2xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i want to so solve this second-order linear differential equation:
$$(1+x^2)y''= 2xy$$
$$y''(x)+x^2y''(x)= 2xy(x)$$
What method is used to solve this differential equation?

Comment: What makes you think it has a closed-form solution?

Comment: @Chappers it does not? why?

Comment: Did you try to do a series solution?

Comment: @Tel0s I don't think Chappers is specifically saying it doesn't have a closed form, but unless you have some reason to believe it does have a closed form, many differential equations do not. Also, closed form can mean different things depending on the context.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: to solve $$ n(n-1) a_n + (n+2)(n+1) a_{n+2} = 2 a_{n-1}$$ does not seem any easier, but it simplifies a bit by setting $a_n=\frac{b_n}{n(n-1)}$ for any $n\geq 2$.

Comment: So if $y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$ we should have $a_n\approx\frac{(-1)^n}{n(n-1)}$ for any large $n$. These are the Taylor coefficients of $(x+1)\log(x+1)$ and the radius of convergence at the origin is clearly one.

Comment: Variation of constants leads to something similar. The solutions of $y''(x)=\frac{2K x}{1+x^2}$ depend on $K(2\arctan x+x\log(1+x^2))$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thank you so much, it seems that i need to study series solution and try to understand

Comment: For the large $x$ behavior, it appears that $y(x)\approx Cx^{1/4}e^{2^{3/2}(x^{1/2}-1)}$ if $x\gg 1$.  I obtained this by putting $y(x)=e^{\int_1^x u(t)dt}$, giving the first order ODE $(1+x^2)(u'(x)+u(x)^2)=2x$.  For large $x$, this looks like $u'(x)+u(x)^2\approx 2/x$.  Assuming that $u'\ll u^2$, we get $u^2\approx 2/x$, i.e. $u\approx\pm \sqrt{2/x}$ if $x>1$.  Putting $u(x)=(1+v(x))\sqrt{2/x}$, where $v\ll 1$, you can refine the approximations further in this way.  If you're interested, this method of "dominant balance" is covered in the (very readable) book by Bender and Orszag.